# SQLFORM.factory dropdownlist not mandatory

Tags: python, web2py

I have a custom form which I have designed using SQLForm.factory. I have created a dropdownlist in it as given below:

```
Field('method',requires=IS_IN_SET([(1,'Method1'),(2,'Method2'),(3,'Method3')],zero='Select'))
```

When I do not select any options from it it shows error as 'value not allowed'. I do not want it to be a mandatory field. I tried to set **required** argument of **Field** class's ****init**** method to **False** but it did not work. Please let me know how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_SET(
    [(1,'Method1'), (2,'Method2'), (3,'Method3')], zero='Select'))
```

Note, the `required` argument to `Field()` is enforced by the DAL upon inserts and results in an exception being thrown upon failure. The `requires` attribute includes a list of one or more validators that are processed during a `SQLFORM` submission -- violations of validators result in errors being displayed on the form, not Python exceptions.